# Searchterm with multiple words not working in Elasticsearch

Tags: elasticsearch

I get my searchterm from req.query, and sometimes the searchterm could be multiple words. For example, it could be "banana splits". However, when I put the multi-word searchterm as a prefix to search my elasticsearch DB, it doesn't return anything even though it should. It works when I only use single-word searchterms, like just "banana". Below is what I have for the body.  Thanks in advance.

```
   body = {
        size: 200,
        from: 0,
        query: {
          bool:{
            should: [
              {
                prefix: {
                  title:{
                    value: searchTerm,
                    boost: 3
                  }
                }
              },
              {
                prefix:{
                  description:{
                    value: searchTerm
                  }
                }
              }
            ]
          }
        }
      }
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [match_phrase prefix](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-match-query-phrase-prefix.html) query that will give you the result if you search for multiple words

Adding a working example with index data, search query, and search result

**Index Data:**

```
{
    "description":"banana is a fruit"
}
{
    "description":"banana splits into 2"
}
{
    "description":"xyz"
}
```

**Search Query:**

```
{
  "query": {
    "match_phrase_prefix": {
      "description": {
        "query": "banana splits"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

**Search Result:**

```
"hits": [
      {
        "_index": "67426581",
        "_type": "_doc",
        "_id": "1",
        "_score": 1.276733,
        "_source": {
          "description": "banana splits into 2"
        }
      }
    ]
```

Comment: @m1i2t3 did you get a chance to go through the answer, looking forward to get feedback from you :-)

Comment: @m1i2t3 any update here? If the answer helped you resolve your issue then please don't forget to accept the answer :-)

Comment: @m1i2t3 can you please reply back ?